# Display Number of Markers on Google Map and Data for that Marker

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I need help with a Google Map system I am constructing. http://helpinspire.me/temp/google-maps/count-markers.html I have 5 json feeds pulling in and displaying based upon which radio button is selected. Then I have an info window for each item that displays its values pulled from the json file when you click a marker.

So the next step I need help on is, I would like to accomplish two things.

1. Render the number of markers that is visible within the zoom level
   the user is at and have that update when the zoom level changes. I
   know I need to use `getMarkerCount` but I am having difficulties
   adding that in.
2. Based on the markers that are visible I would like to add up two variables: `available seats` and `user count`. So if three markers are visible within that zoom level I would like to display the total available seats and user count.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I do usually with Google Maps is keep a reference of all active markers and infowindows in arrays. Doing so, you could iterate through your markers and check whether they're within the map. Use getBounds() to get the LatLng of the corners of the map. Then loop through your array of markers, checking whether each marker's lat/lng is within the bounds.